# How do I refer to an outside alias from inside a piglatin macro?

Tags: macros, apache-pig

I have an alias which I want to use in a macro:

```
foo = ....;
define my_macro (z) returns y {
   $y = join $z in id, foo on id;
};
a = my_macro(b);
```

Alas, I get the error:

```
Undefined alias: macro_my_macro_foo_0
```

I can, of course, pass `foo` as en argument:

```
define my_macro (foo, z) returns y {
   $y = join $z in id, $foo on id;
};
a = my_macro(foo,b);
```

Is this the right way?

If `foo` is actually a relatively complicated object, will it be recalculated for each macroexpansion of `my_macro`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the second approach is right one, you need to pass the alias as an argument to macro otherwise it will not be visible inside macro.

on the other side, alias defined inside the macro will not be access outside, in-case if you want to access the alias then use this format `macro_<my macro_name>_<alias name suffixed with an instance>`

I have simulated both the options
1. accessing alias from outside to inside macro(using argument)
2. accessing alias from inside macro to outside (using macro expanded name format)

example
**in.txt**

```
a,10,1000
b,20,2000
c,30,3000
```

**in1.txt**

```
10,aaa
20,bbb
30,ccc
```

**Pigscript:**

```
define my_macro (foo,z) returns y {
   $y = join $z by g1, $foo by f2;
   test = FOREACH $y generate $0,$2;
};

foo = LOAD 'in.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1,f2,f3);
b  = LOAD 'in1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (g1,g2);
C = my_macro(foo,b);
DUMP C;
--DUMP macro_my_macro_test_0;
```

**Output of option1:**
DUMP C

```
(10,aaa,a,10,1000)
(20,bbb,b,20,2000)
(30,ccc,c,30,3000)
```

**Output of option2:**
DUMP macro_my_macro_test_0

```
(10,a)
(20,b)
(30,c)
```

There are some restrictions in using the macro, like
1. not allowed inside nested for each stmt
2. not allowed to use any grunt commands
3. not allowed to include a user-defined schema

I suggest you to refer the below document link, this will definitely give some better ideas about macros and also how to use inside pig script.
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/cont.html#macros